# Vmware sphere setting up external network

Tags: networking, centos, vmware-esxi

I've just setup vmware vsphere 5 on a remote server (rented dedicated server). I've added my first VPS (centos 5.8) barebones. It's not finding any IP (internal or external) on boot. I've had an extra external IP assigned to my server that I wanted to use on the VPS. I tried editing the eth0 config and adding the IP in there and turning off the DHCP, but it can't find any IP or ping google or do any networking type things.

How do I route the IP to my VPS so I can access it remotely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked it out. I had to create a virtual mac address and forward it to my server

Comment: Yeah I will, unfortunately I can't until tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running vsphere 5, you're going to need more than a single IP address.

For starters, vsphere needs an IP for its management interface, and then on top of that each VM will need its own as well. If you have external storage accessed over IP (iSCSI or NFS), that'll need to be accessed by a separate interface as well, which will need its own IP.

Comment: Hey, yeah I have 4IPS routed to the esxi vsphere 5 box, I just don't know how to route them through to the VMs

Comment: hrmm.... routed as in... statically routed or they're on the same subnet as that first IP?

Comment: Statically routed I believe